# Dealing with questions on vectors and matrices with variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I'm running into a lot of questions on linear algebra lately where, instead of using constant numbers in matrices and vectors (these are questions which I have no problems in answering), they use a mix of constants and a variable *a*. I'm finding these difficult to answer. For example:

For each value of a, find the rank and nullity of the matrix, v1=(a,a,a), v2=(0,1,2) v3=(1,0,-1). I understand rank and nullity but again, I'm thrown off by what is being asked regarding a. If a=0 then the rank is 2 and nullity is 1, correct? Then if a>0, we need to perform additional row operations to reduce to row echelon form. But this can't be done with a variable? I'm mostly having trouble with how I could express the answer correctly considering the inclusions of the variable a. I'm only used to answering LA questions on problems with constants so this has thrown me off.

In general, how can I deal with questions of this type?

Comment: First, observe that $v_2$ and $v_3$ are independent. That means the rank is at least $2$ and nullity can be at most $1$. Now in this case, you can just evaluate the determinant and see when it is zero to make rank $2$ and nullity $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we are interested in the matrix whose rows are $v_1, v_2, v_3$ (it doesn't really matter as $\mathrm{rank} A = \mathrm{rank} A^T$ so we could as well put them as columns). Thus,

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} a & a & a \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 1 & 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Instead of handling immediately the case where $a \neq 0$ and $a = 0$, I suggest that you delay it by replacing the third row with the first row, leading to

$$ A' = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ a & a & a \end{pmatrix}. $$

By subtracting $a \times $ the first row from the third row, we obtain

$$ A'' =  \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & a & 2a \end{pmatrix}.$$

Continuing with the second row, we subtract $a \times $ the second row from the third row and obtain

$$ A '' = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Now it is clear that $A''$ has rank two no matter what $a$ is. In general, you won't be able to avoid case analysis but you can delay it so that expressions involving the parameter will appear only in the last rows which will make the analysis easier.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think to use 'a' as a multiple in row operations, I just thought they couldn't be done with variables such as that. In another situation, I'm asked to find the dimensions for row and column of a matrix comprising of v1=(a,1,a) and v2=(1,a,1). However, I can't see hoe row operations can be used here to eliminate 'a'. In cases such as this, what can be done? And thanks for the help.

Comment: Do the same. Replace the first row with the second row and use the first row to eliminate $a$. You will be left with a matrix of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & 1 \\ 0 & 1 - a^2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. The first row is always non-zero and the second row will be linearly dependent on the first row if and only if it is the zero row. So the rank of the matrix is two if $a \neq \pm 1$ and one if $a = \pm 1$.